# Using JSON data in a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am returing JSON data as a response in a web service I am writing.

I am wondering what is the best way to consume the data, returned to a Javascript function (passed as an argument).

Do I:

1. use eval()
2. use Doug Crawfords jSon parser to parse the JSON data into a Javascript object
3. simply use the returned data as an object literal

BTW, I am still learning Javascript, (just started reading the Definitive Guide 2 days ago) so if my question seems a bit naive or asinine - bear with me.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a few things, first, on the web service side:

1. If a `callback=functionName` parameter is passed in the query string, then return the properly serialized JSON as the only parameter to the callback function (In this case `functionName`
2. If no callback was requested, then simply return the properly serialized JSON string. (This is helpful for when other languages consume the JSON. PHP or Ruby for instance)

Then, as far as consuming it, if you are on the same domain as the web service, you can retrieve the code and use the [`json2.js` parser](http://www.JSON.org/js.html) to parse it. If you are on a separate domain, use the `callback` parameter when requesting the data, and make sure you set up a function to handle the callback.

**Simple example (Using PHP):**

```
<?php
   $callback = null;
   if( isset($_REQUEST['callback']) ){
     $callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];
   }

   $fakeData = array( 'key' => 'value');
   $json     = json_encode( $fakeData );

   echo $callback ? "$callback($json)" : $json;
?>
```

**JS (On different domain than the web service):**

```
function handleCallback( data ){
  alert( data.key );
}

function get_json(){
   // Dynamically create the script element
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src  = "http://yourwebservice.com/service/?callback=handleCallback";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( script );
}
```

Calling `get_json` would dynamically create the request (as a script element due to cross domain restrictions. You can't use XMLHttpRequest to make cross domain requests in most browsers), and the PHP returned script would correctly call the `handleCallback` function when the script returns.

Comment: The latest versions of all the major browsers support native JSON, so scripts should check for it before loading json2.js.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can set it up so it returns as a JSON object.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your webservice is decorated with ScriptService attribute:
I would suggest using json2.js to handle the json clientside. It defers to native implementations when they are available.

Answer (score 0):

**(1). use eval()**

Only if you're certain the data is clean. I'd never trust anything from an outside source.

**(2). use Doug Crawfords jSon parser to parse the JSON data into a Javascript object**

Best idea overall. Even jQuery uses plain old eval() to parse JSON.

**(3). simply use the returned data as an object literal**

When it's returned, it's just a string, not an object unless passed through one of the two aforementioned functions, or wrapped in a function ala [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).

Comment: @bdl "Even jQuery uses plain old eval() to parse JSON" is incorrect as of jQuery 1.4

Comment: @Doug> Thanks for the clarification. Edit: apparently they haven't changed the API docs, because it still claims to use eval().